# antd: 'inputValue' prop of Select component is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using `antd`'s (`v3.23.1`) `Select` component with `mode="multiple"`. After typing in Select search field and clicking outside, clears the searched text from the input. So I'm trying to make controlled component by persisting the search text in state variable(inside `onSearch` method) and passing it to `inputValue` prop of Select component(as given in the [document](https://ant.design/components/select/)), but it is not working, state variable holds proper value but however search text in input gets cleared. Actually `inputValue` prop is not working at all I guess, because even if I pass '' to `inputValue` prop, it works as an uncontrolled component. I tried setting `autoClearSearchValue` to false - but this persists search value only after selecting or deselecting option not on click outside

This issue can be reproducible [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hooks-792kz?fontsize=14).

So, is any other way I can persist search text even after clicking outside?

Answer (score 1):

It's by design and there is no plan in changing such behavior.

You can render another `Input` component and persist the search value with the `Select` component.

You can check [this issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/18683) on `antd` GitHub.